# Join a VM to domain automatically which was created using terraform

Tags: terraform

How do I join a VM created using terraform to domain?

I tried using resource azurerm_virtual_machine_extension with azure,VM got created successfully but domain joining dint happen.

***Error***:Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'join-domain'. Error message: \"Join completed for Domain '***.com'\".

Comment: Don't give us your actual domain, but did you put the appropriate domain information in that script? Use fake data to represent your actual domain info and use the EDIT button to make your question more clear please.

Comment: yes,I had used the correct domain in the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "domain_join_extension" {
  name                 = "join-domain"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "fileUris": ["<URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT>"],
      "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File domain-join.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Replace "<URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT>" with the publicly accessible URL of the uploaded PowerShell script.

Apply the Terraform configuration:
Run "terraform apply" to apply the changes and create the VM with the extension.
The custom script extension will execute the PowerShell script on the VM, and it should join the VM to the specified domain.